# What does "vector, 090 for bogey" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Top Gun (1986)*, a radar operator speaks on radio:

> Radar Operator: Ghost Rider, this is Strike. We have unknown aircraft.
> Inbound, Mustang. Your **vector, 090 for bogey**.

What does "vector, 090 for bogey" mean?

Comment: Please include details of the research you have done on this question and read https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: What research have you done? For example, have you searched for it on the Internet, or check up in a dictionary? Please read [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) article about how to ask a good question, especially for the "search and research" section. I've flagged your post and downvoted it. It's also better for you as it becomes easier to get a good answer.

Comment: This is the original text from one of the flagging options: "This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or provide more context. See: [Details, Please.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In air navigation  communications, a vector is an instruction to steer in a compass direction, given in degrees, and in military aviation, a 'bogey' is a possible enemy or opposition aircraft.

> You have to steer a course heading 90 degrees (i.e. due east) to go towards the enemy
> aircraft.

[image]